# Looking for Documentation for TiddlyWiki Plugins

Tags: javascript, tiddlywiki

I have a couple of ideas for [TiddlyWiki](http://tiddlywiki.org) plugins I'd like to write. However, I've been unable to find any reference info for the "TiddlyWiki plugin API" (which doesn’t seem to be formally defined).

Does such documentation exist, or do I just need to look at the TiddlyWiki source and some example plugins?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While there is no comprehensive official API documentation, there are several community projects:
http://groups.google.com/group/tiddlywikidev/browse_thread/thread/afe860dd7a7fef77

(Part of the issue is that due to its flexibility, the entirety of TiddlyWiki can be considered an API... )

The TiddlyWiki community is extremely friendly and helpful - if you post your questions to the mailing list, you will get competent help.